# Can't see environment variables set in docker-compose from sbt

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, environment-variables

I have a dockerfile:

```
FROM mozilla/sbt:8u212_1.3.4

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN sbt compile

CMD sbt run
```

I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    my-service:
        build: .
        environment:
            - KEY=VALUE
```

My scala project looks like this:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  println(System.getenv("KEY")
}
```

but when I run docker-compose up it just prints `null`, instead of `VALUE`

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works for me. Maybe you over-simplified your example?! Maybe you forgot to rebuild the image when testing? Maybe there's just a typo somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid none of those three are the case. I managed to get it working when I used `CMD [ "sbt", "run" ]`, but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

First, Check if the variable it's in the container.
Run de container and enter in it:

```
$ docker exec -it <IDcontainer> /bin/bash
# echo $KEY
```

Maybe the problem is in the program and not in the container.
Bye